# Field Pack not storing icon hex

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack

I have a Field Pack Dropdown field for authors to select an icon. In the field settings I have the following options:

```
&#x1F440; : View
&#x1F4DD; : Compose
&#x1F512; : Lock
&#x1F513; : Unlock
&#x1F511; : Key
&#x1F4DE; : Phone
&#x2709; : Mail
&#x1F4AC; : Chat
&#x1F465; : Users
&#xE6D0; : Location
&#xEB85; : Connection
&#x201C; : Quote
&#xED50; : List
&#x2699; : Settings
&#x1F4C5; : Calendar
```

This shows up in the publish page as expected:

```
<select name="field_id_5">
    <option value="&#x1F440;">View</option>
    <option value="&#x1F4DD;">Compose</option>
    <option value="&#x1F512;">Lock</option>
    <option value="&#x1F513;">Unlock</option>
    <option value="&#x1F511;">Key</option>
    <option value="&#x1F4DE;">Phone</option>
    <option value="&#x2709;">Mail</option>
    <option value="&#x1F4AC;">Chat</option>
    <option value="&#x1F465;">Users</option>
    <option value="&#xE6D0;">Location</option>
    <option value="&#xEB85;">Connection</option>
    <option value="&#x201C;">Quote</option>
    <option value="&#xED50;">List</option>
    <option value="&#x2699;">Settings</option>
    <option value="&#x1F4C5;">Calendar</option>
</select>
```

The problem is the field is not storing the data, and on the front-end calling the field outputs a null value.

Any ideas what the issue could be, or any workarounds I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the'&#' characters from the dropdown options

```
&#x1F440; : View
```

has now become

```
x1F440; : View
```

and added those characters to my template output instead.

```
&#{standard_icon}
```

The field is storing the value as expected and the icon is being output fine in the template.